# Why does $(document).height() return too high number?

Tags: jquery, html

I am alerting my document height:

```
alert($(document).height());
```

The result is 3307px while the full web page has roughly 1800px.

From other answers here on SO, I learned I needed to check `DOCTYPE` which I did and it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any idea why can document height show higher number than expected?

There are no hidden elements in the page, or anything like that.

**EDIT:**
The reason it was showing that high number was that at the time of me retrieving the document height, my menu, was containing some elements that increased the overall height.

Comment: how do you know the web page has 1800px (roughly, whatever that means - there must be an exact figure surely)? Where is that data coming from?

Comment: Roughly I know it from the resolution of my screen and sum up with the point where I end up when I scroll to very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
alert($(window).height());
```

if you want , browser window height;

Comment: I don't want browser window height, I want my web page height.

Comment: are you using browser zoom ?

Answer (score -1):

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$( window ).height();

// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: read the comments of each function.
source: below URL
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html this should give you an answerforwhat you are looking for..

Comment: read about viewport content so that you can identify what will come if we use document height